# Is the coordinate ring of a variety a finitely generated algebra?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $X$ be a (not necessarily affine) variety over $k$. Is the coordinate ring of $X$ ($k[X]$ or $O_{X}(X)$) always a finitely generated $k$-algebra?

Comment: I would not call this ring the coordinate ring except in the affine case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Feed google with "variety whose ring of global sections is not finitely generated". One gets [An example of a nice variety whose ring of global sections is not finitely generated](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/nonfg.pdf) by Ravi Vakil.

Comment: Note that Vakil's example is minimal: their is no such example in dimension $2$ e.g. by Cor 6.3 of this paper (http://reh.math.uni-duesseldorf.de/%7Eschroeer/publications_pdf/contractible_curves.pdf) of Schroer.

Comment: Please stop the upvoting. Everyone can google this, this was my message sort of  ...

Comment: Alternate link: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=variety+whose+ring+of+global+sections+is+not+finitely+generated